# List inside the scope of a recursive function is not updating

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

```
def largest_to_last(arr, index):
    if(len(arr) == 1):
        return 
    largest_to_last(arr[:-1], index-1)
    if(arr[index-1] > arr[index]):
        arr[index-1], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[index-1]
        # print(arr)
        return
    
arr = [1,4,2,8,5,6]
largest_to_last(arr, len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

I have to push the largest element to the end of the array using recursion. I am not able to find any mistake here, can someone please help?

Comment: I have a hard time getting your logic. What sorting algorithm is this?

Comment: In short, I want to push the largest element of the array to the end of the array.

Comment: `sort(arr[:-1], index-1)` is creating a copy of the array and passing that in (as opposed to passing in the actual array ... since it is never returned, it is basically discarded (including any sorts)

Comment: i think he cant event get to that point yet ... hes trying to debug his program, and then understand and modify it .... or maybe im reading too much into it

Comment: @ruakh a single pass of bubble sort can be used to get the largest number in the array at the sorted position, that's what OP is doing as opposed to a complete ```sort```. Wrong name for the function though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `arr[:-1]`, a copy of the array is created an changes aren't reflected to the original list. Here is a fixed, easy implementation:

```py
def sort(arr, index):
    if(len(arr) == 2):
        if(arr[index-1] > arr[index]):
            arr[index-1], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[index-1]
        return arr
    arr = sort(arr[:index], index-1)+[arr[index]]
    if(arr[index-1] > arr[index]):
        arr[index-1], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[index-1]
    return arr
    
arr = [1,4,2,8,5,6]
arr = sort(arr, len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```